# Selected Spinner value not being changed when selected and continuing to be null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Before I start I just want to tell you that I have been looking through this website and others for quite a while before I decided to post this. I have done my research, analyzed my code and I have pinpointed the problem. I hope you could just help me find the solution for it and tell me why it is happening.

The string value 'carModel' is supposed to be initialised to the value which the user selects, however, it fails to do so and when is tested for equality in the second java class, it says -

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

The same thing is happening for the 'Zone' value of the string. I think there is something wrong in the way I initialised the values

**Main class**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> SelectedOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    public String CarMake, InsuranceComp;
    public String Zone;
    String CarModel;
    public double ATDper;
    public int YOM, YOPE, ZDepPer, NCB, ZDepAdd, OwnerDriv, PaidDriv, Passenger, CODisc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText ZeroDep = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText ZeroDepAdd = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText CODiscount = findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        ZeroDep.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                ZDepPer = Integer.parseInt(ZeroDep.getText().toString().replace("%", ""));
                return false;
            }
        });

        ZeroDepAdd.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                ZeroDepAdd.getText().clear();
                ZDepAdd = Integer.parseInt(ZeroDepAdd.getText().toString().replace("%",""));
                return false;
            }
        });

        CODiscount.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                CODisc = Integer.parseInt(CODiscount.getText().toString().replace("%", ""));
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button calcButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, output_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        Spinner carCompSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.car_companies,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        carCompSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
        carCompSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                CarMake = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) { }
        });


        final Spinner carModSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.car_model,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        carModSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
        carModSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                **CarModel = carModSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();// carModel is not being initialised and is remaining as null
                Log.d("Calculator", CarModel);
            }**
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) { }
        });

        final Spinner YOMSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.year_of_manuf,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        YOMSpinner.setAdapter(adapter3);
        YOMSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                YOM = Integer.parseInt(YOMSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        final Spinner YOPESpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter4= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.year_of_pex,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        YOPESpinner.setAdapter(adapter4);
        YOPESpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                YOPE = Integer.parseInt(YOPESpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        final Spinner ZSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter5= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.zone,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ZSpinner.setAdapter(adapter5);
        ZSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            **@Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Zone = ZSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Log.d("Calculator", Zone); //Here Zone is printed out perfectly in the logcat, however, the value does not change
            }**

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        final Spinner NCBSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner9);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter9= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.NCB,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        NCBSpinner.setAdapter(adapter9);
        NCBSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                NCB = Integer.parseInt(NCBSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().replace("%",""));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}
        });
        final Spinner ATSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner10);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter10= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.AntiTheft,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ATSpinner.setAdapter(adapter10);
        ATSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ATDper = Double.parseDouble(ATSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().replace("%",""));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        final Spinner ODSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner15);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter15= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.ownerDriv,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ODSpinner.setAdapter(adapter15);
        ODSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                OwnerDriv = Integer.parseInt(ODSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().replace("%",""));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}
        });
        final Spinner PDSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner16);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter16= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.paidDriv,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        PDSpinner.setAdapter(adapter16);
        PDSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                PaidDriv = Integer.parseInt(PDSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().replace("%",""));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        final Spinner PsngrSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner17);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter17= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.passenger,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        PsngrSpinner.setAdapter(adapter17);
        PsngrSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Passenger = Integer.parseInt(PsngrSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().replace("%",""));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        final Spinner InsCompSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner19);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter19= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.insuranceComp,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        InsCompSpinner.setAdapter(adapter19);
        InsCompSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                InsuranceComp = InsCompSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The part where the problem occurs is this and other similar methods.

```
final Spinner carModSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.car_model,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        carModSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
        carModSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                CarModel = carModSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();// carModel is not being initialised and is remaining as null
                Log.d("Calculator", ""+ adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) { }
        });
```

**Second class**

```
 if (CarModel.equalsIgnoreCase("City")){ //error occurs here as it says CarModel is null
            CC = 1200;
            switch(carAge){
                case 1: ExShowRoomPrice = 950000;
                    break;
                case 2: ExShowRoomPrice = 760000;
                    break;
                case 3: ExShowRoomPrice = 665000;
                    break;
                case 4: ExShowRoomPrice = 570000;
                    break;
                case 5: ExShowRoomPrice = 475000;
                    break;
                case 6: ExShowRoomPrice = 451250;
                    break;
                case 7: ExShowRoomPrice = 427500;
                    break;
                case 8: ExShowRoomPrice = 403750;
                    break;
                case 9: ExShowRoomPrice = 380000;
                    break;
                case 10: ExShowRoomPrice = 356250;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (CarModel.equalsIgnoreCase("Amaze")){ // and so on
```

The same problem also occurs when zone is tested for equality

```
if (CC<1000 && carAge < 5){
            if (Zone.equals("A")) IRDATariff = 3.127; //throws the same error as it says for carModel and says that it is a null reference
            if (Zone.equals("B")) IRDATariff = 3.039;
        }
```

The change of values is seen in the Logcat quite clearly

**Logcat**

```
D/Calculator: City
D/Calculator: A
D/Calculator: B
D/Calculator: BR-V
D/Calculator: Civic
D/Calculator: CRV
D/Calculator: Brio
D/Calculator: A
```

How can Zone and carModel be null in the second class when in the logcat they are outputted as their values?

Comment: add an xml file

Comment: I already have one for each class but cannot show it because it will exceed the word limit